# Meteor Impact probability

Tags: probability

given that 1 meteor hits once every 30 years: what is probability that it does not hit once in 100 years?

probability that it hits once every 30 year is 1/30 but I can't figure the steps out after thatß

Comment: How are the hits distributed? Binominal? Poisson?

Comment: this sounds like a homework problem. typically a meteor hit is a rare event and can be modelled as a poisson random variable. let $X$ be the number of hits in $30$ years, then $E(X) = 1 = \lambda$. Let $Y$ be the number of hits in $100$ years then $Y \sim POI(100/30)$. from this $P(Y=1)$ is ready to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, if it really does hit every 30 years, then the probability that it hits once in 100 years is 100% (in fact, it'll hit three times). I think what they mean by "hits once every 30 years" is that every year it has a 1 in 30 chance to hit. So you imagine that every year, someone flips a coin that has a $\frac 1 {30}$ chance of coming up heads, and if it comes up heads, the meteor hits.

If I flip that coin 100 times, what are the odds of getting heads at least once? The trick to these problems is to instead consider the odds of getting tails every time. Can you compute that?